# Передача ID dropdownlist в несколько action

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Возникла такая задача: при выборе элемента из dropdownlist значение id нужно передать в два action, но onchange выполняет только первый запрос.
Код запроса:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'ID_region')->dropDownList($arrReg,[
        'prompt'=>'Область',
    'onchange'=>'$.post("/enrollee/area/lists?ID='.'"+$(this).val(),function (data){
     $("select#enrollee-id_area").html(data);
     });' and  '$.post("/enrollee/city/lists?ID='.'"+$(this).val(),function (data){
     $("select#enrollee-id_city").html(data);
     });' ,

]) ?>
```

Comment: Предлагаю использовать две модели в один action. Тут будет по проще и понятнее.

Comment: А onchange не может два запроса выполнить?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'ID_region')->dropDownList($arrReg,[
        'prompt'=>'Область',
    'onchange'=>'$.post("/enrollee/area/lists?ID='.'"+$(this).val(),function (data){
     $("select#enrollee-id_area").html(data);
     }); $.post("/enrollee/city/lists?ID='.'"+$(this).val(),function (data){
     $("select#enrollee-id_city").html(data);
     });',

]) ?>
```